# нужно чтобы каждая строка выводилась с определенным цветом, в последовательности белый, красный, черный

Tags: python, colorama

Создал программу, ради прикола, которая выводит 1000 - 7 пока не станет меньше нуля,
нужно чтобы каждая строка выводилась с определенным цветом, в последовательности белый, красный, черный, не могу это сделать. Что-то уже написал, но выдает каждую строку по три раза

```
import time
import sys
from colorama import init
from random import choice

init(autoreset=True)

a = 1007
y = 1000

color = {'white': '\x1b[30m',
         'red': '\x1b[31m',
         'black': '\x1b[37m'}

color_key = ['white', 'red', 'black']

ck = 0
print(color[color_key[ck]])


while a != 13:
    a -= 7
    y -= 7
    x = ('{0} - 7 = {1}'.format(a, y))
    for i in color_key:
        print(color[i] + x)
    time.sleep(1/25)

ya_ghoul = ['Я ','г', 'у', 'л', 'ь']

for ghoul in ya_ghoul:
    sys.stdout.write(ghoul)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: Itertools cycle

Comment: спасибо тебе, я наконец-то это сделал